# Android RecyclerView show data even not exists

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, picasso

i have a RecyclerView with 30 rows of data. some rows have image that i get and show it with picasso.
the problem is that, image box repeated every 8 rows even that row don't have image.
i check that if image is empty don't show it, but show it yet.

[image: here is an image about it]

```
JobAdapter.java
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder) holder;
            JobClass current=data.get(position);
            myHolder.name.setText(current.title);
            myHolder.manager.setText(current.manager);
            String phone= (String) new KerashDao(context).JobinfoGetValue(current.job_id.toString(),new KerashDao(context).SettingGetValue("phone").toString());
            myHolder.phonecall.setText(phone.toString());

            try {
                if(!current.image.isEmpty()) {
                    Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(current.image)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.icn_loading)
                        .into(myHolder.picture, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {myHolder.picture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                myHolder.picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){Log.i("JobAdapter2",ex.getMessage().toString()+"");}

        }
```

Comment: is it staying permanently  even after scrolling ?

Comment: @Redman. yes its repeated every 8 rows. and i check image field with `is_empty` ,`equal("")` .

Comment: What device is that, its so big?

Comment: @Redman. no, it's usual. i create this photo to show you what is my problem. i test it on my phone and The problem is still there

Comment: I dont know whats causing problem,  try to Log  the value  position+current.image inside `if(!current.image.isEmpty())` and see if they are same

Comment: @Redman, i log `if(!current.image.isEmpty())` and its empty. but still image is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RecyclerView` *recycles* the views that represent each row. This means that a given view will be re-used by another row once it scrolls off screen. Since you loaded an image into that view at some point, it will stick around until you clear it.

Add an `else` clause to your `if(!current.image.isEmpty())` statement that clears the image in your `ImageView`.